# Geodesic on a right circular cone problem.

Tags: geodesic

Is there a solution available to solve geodesic on a right circular cone problem?

We are given a cone with diameter $D$ and height $H$. The center of the base of the cone is at $(x=0,y=0,z=0)$ and the cone point is at $(0,0,H)$, The geodesic goes through $(0,R,0)$ and $(0,-R,0)$ on the cone base.

- a.  Determine the arc length formula for the geodesic.
- b.  Determine the equation for the geodesic.

Let $ L= \sqrt{R^2 + H^2}$  be the radius of the circle or slant radius of cone

and let $(\theta, c,s) $  be the (central angle in radians , chord length, arc length) respectively. Then, are the following OK?

$$s = \theta * L, s = \pi * R, $$

$$ \theta = \pi  R / L,\quad  c = 2 L* \sin(\pi * R / 2L ).$$

Comment: If you cut the cone surface along a ray emanating from the apex, you will see that the cone is isometric to a circle sector, so the length of your geodetic is just the length of a chord in a circle, namely $$ 2\sqrt{R^2+H^2} \sin \left( \frac{\pi R}{2\sqrt{R^2+H^2}} \right). $$

Comment: I will do that tonight, I cannot at the moment. Feel free to send me a reminder if I forget that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you cut the cone surface along a ray emanating from the apex, the cone is isometric to a circle sector, so the length of the geodesic is the length of a chord in a circle.

The geodesic between (x=0, y=R, z=0) and (x=0, y=-R, z=0) on the cone base appears as a straight red line in the attached picture.

Attached is a picture of the "unfolding" of the right circular cone.

[image: "unfolding" of right circular cone]

Answer (score 5):

[image]

We just have to consider that a right circular cone is isometric with a circle sector. If we assume that the depicted cone has base radius $R$ and height $h$, by "unfolding" it we get a circle sector for a circle having radius $\sqrt{R^2+h^2}$, with arc length $2\pi R$. By "unfolding" the depicted geodesic between two opposite points on the base of the cone, we have a chord in a circle with radius $\sqrt{R^2+h^2}$ and the length of the corresponding arc is $\pi R$. It easily follows that the length of the depicted geodesic is

$$ 2\sqrt{R^2+h^2}\sin\left(\frac{\pi R}{2\sqrt{R^2+h^2}}\right). $$

When $h\to 0^+$, the length of such path tends to $2R$ (not to $\pi R$) and there is nothing strange in that: if the height of the cone is small, it is faster to reach the opposite point by going through the vertex of the cone, instead of making a half-turn around the base.

Comment: @BruceBerentsen: what kind of circle sector do you get by "unfolding" a right circular cone?

Comment: Please refer to my answer.

Comment: is there any special name for this geodesic?

Answer (score 0):

Of course there is a solution without Maple. You just have to use geodesic polar coordinates on the surface of the cone. They are like usual polar coordinates in a disk, just here the disc has a cone singularity at its center and its angle is $\Theta = \frac{2\pi R}{\sqrt{R^2+H^2}}$ is radians, assuming that $2R = D$ in your post. According to my brief (and maybe not too precise) calculations, the geodesic polar coordinate representation of the surface of the cone is 
\begin{align}
x &= \frac{R \, \rho}{\sqrt{R^2+H^2}}\cos\left(\frac{\theta \, \sqrt{R^2+H^2}}{R}\right)\\
y &= \frac{R \, \rho}{\sqrt{R^2+H^2}}\sin\left(\frac{\theta\,  \sqrt{R^2+H^2}}{R}\right)\\
z &= H - \frac{H \, \rho}{\sqrt{R^2+H^2}}
\end{align}
where the coordinate parameters are $(\theta,\rho) \, \in \, [0, \Theta]\times(0, \sqrt{R^2+H^2}]$
As the straight lines in polar coordinates are $$\rho = \frac{c_0}{a_0 \cos{\theta} + b_0 \sin{\theta}},$$ the geodesics on the cone are
\begin{align}
x(\theta) &= \frac{R \, c_0}{(a_0 \cos{\theta} + b_0 \sin{\theta})\sqrt{R^2+H^2}}\,\cos\left(\frac{\theta \, \sqrt{R^2+H^2}}{R}\right)\\
y(\theta) &= \frac{R \, c_0}{(a_0 \cos{\theta} + b_0 \sin{\theta})\sqrt{R^2+H^2}} \,\sin\left(\frac{\theta\,  \sqrt{R^2+H^2}}{R}\right)\\
z(\theta) &= H - \frac{H \, c_0}{(a_0 \cos{\theta} + b_0 \sin{\theta})\sqrt{R^2+H^2}}.
\end{align}

Comment: @BruceBerentsen No, $a, b, c$ are not the parameters of a plane in 3D space. Intersecting the cone with a plane does not yield a geodesic. Geodesics on the cone, as curves in 3D, are more intricate and are not planar curves. And there is no problem with the argument $\theta$. I don't know why you assume that it has to be between $0$ and $2\pi$. It doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

An exact way is .... if radius at closest point to axis of symmetry near cone vertex is $r_{min}$ and cone semi-vertical angle

$$  \alpha  = \sin ^{-1} \frac{R}{\sqrt { R^2+H^2}},  $$

then

$$ r_{min}  = r \cos ( \theta\cdot  \sin \alpha) $$

Arc lengths and geodesics are obtained by integration using :

$$ ds^2 = dr^2 + dz^2 + ( r d \theta)^2 $$ and using Clairaut's Law:

$$ r_{min}= r^2 \cdot \frac{d \theta }{ ds } = r \cdot \sin \psi $$

EDIT 1:

which gives

$$\frac{d \psi}{ds} = - \sin \alpha = -\frac12, $$

say as an example of $30^0$ semi-vertical angle cone. Then we  must have

$$ \psi= (\pi/4, \pi/2, 3 \pi/4 ) $$

respectively at points of (entry, $r_{min}$,  exit) of geodesic line on the truncated cone. If R = 1, these radii are accordingly  $( 1, 1/\sqrt 2, 1 ). $

Calculation of radius and arc length of cone /geodesic from middle position:

$$ dr / \sin \alpha  = r d \theta \cot \psi$$

$$ dr / \sin \alpha  = r d \theta \sqrt{(r/r_{min} )^2-1 }$$
Integrating , integration constant =0 with central boundary condition

$$ r = r_{min} \sec ( \theta \sin \alpha ); z = r \cot \alpha =  r_{min}\cdot \cot\alpha\, \sec ( \theta \sin \alpha ) \tag {1} $$

which is the required equation of polar projection of geodesic.

Considering differential lengths/angles

$$ d \theta /ds = \sin \psi /r = r _{min} /r^2 $$

plug in from above and integrate

$$ s/r_{min} = \tan (\theta \, \sin \alpha ) / \sin \, \alpha \tag{2} $$

which is general equation of (semi) arc length of geodesic arc.

For $ \alpha =0 $, or $ \pi/2  $ we have $ s = r _{min} \tan \theta $ as we can expect.

Again plugin from (1) for semi-arc lengthFor

$$ s /r = \sin ( \theta \sin \alpha )/\sin \alpha  $$

At `the required`particular  diametrical opposite position $ \theta = \pi/2 $ the full arclength $$ = \sqrt{R^2+H^2}\sin ( \pi R/(2 \sqrt{R^2+H^2})) \tag {3} $$

However it is more convenient to retain $(r-\theta, s- \theta)$ forms.

[image: Geodesics on Cone]

Comment: Not sure, unable to follow his (a,b,c) part. By geodesic polar coordinates he is( I think ) using a polar grid of the developed flat cone sheet with apex as center.

Comment: Equation of geodesic  is given in (1) parametrically $ r (\theta), z (\theta) $

Comment: Yes that is indeed the answer for your first question a, but not second question b.

Comment: The equation of the right circular cone is given by: 
(H * x)^2 + (H * y)^2 = ((H - z) * R)^2
 
Thank you for your analysis and results for the right circular cone problem. 
 
We have yet to derive the equation of the two geodesics between 
(0,R,0) and (0,-R,0) for the right circular cone.  Any suggestions ?

Comment: No, the parametric equation of geodesic $ r(\theta),  z(\theta)$  has been already given in (1). What is the second geodesic you are referring to? By definition, there is only one (minimum of all other possible) geodesic.It has also been pictured.

Comment: The base of the cone is at (x=0, y=0, z=0) and the cone apex is at (0, 0, H).  Let L = sqrt(R^2 + H^2) be the slant radius of the cone measured in inches.  Let theta = central angle measured in radians.  Cos and Sec are non-negative if  -pi / 2 <= theta <= pi / 2  Let r(min) = radius at closest point to axis of symmetry of cone.  
r(min) = R * cos(pi * R / 2 * L)   r = r(min) * sec(theta * R / L)  when theta = 0, then r = r(min)   z = H - (H / R) * r(min) * sec(theta * R / L)  when theta = 0, then z = z(max) = H - (H / R) * rmin)  The equation of the geodesic is given by (r, z). .